# file name grayed out in browse window when try to upload video file to my website in mac safari

Tags: file-upload, safari

when user click on browse bottom and try to upload video file to the site (MP4 for example) from mac safari the file grayed out (disabled) and it can't be selected.

it happens only for video files and only in mac Safari.

in others browsers in work good.

when I try to upload MP3 file it also work.

Answer (score 2):

I experience this "bug" on a daily basis with Safari. The bug has not been patched or fixed and still exists today with Safari 13.0.2 and macOS Catalina.

The workaround is this. When the file selection window opens, control-click on the file and select Quick View from the menu. Then go back to the file selection window and you will be able to click on it for upload. Ridiculous that this hasn't been fixed by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

select the file (either jpeg or png)  and rename to *filename.jpeg><filename.png>* so the file type remain same.

worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade safari to the latest version since this was a bug that mac had which they patched in the most recent version since others had the problem too.